# Работа скрипта через интервал?

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопка, которая по клику обновляет содержимое блока с `id="dle-content"`.
Как сделать, чтобы этот скрипт срабатывал каждые 5 минут, а не по клику?

```
<a onclick="custom_reload('dle-content');return false;">reload</a>
```

и скрипт

```
function custom_reload(area){
    ShowLoading();
    $.post(window.location.href,{},function(d){
        HideLoading();
        $("#"+area).html($("#"+area,d).html());
    });
return false;
}
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

Comment: Не знаю как это сюда прикрутить.

Comment: обратитесь на фриланс. Там всё за вас сделают

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(custom_reload, 300000, 'dle-content');
```